# How can I make a wildcard subdomain in my custom domain in GitHub Pages?

Tags: github

I’m trying to link `*.example.com` (not my real site) to my GitHub Pages, but when I type that into my custom domain settings in my repository, it says that the domain is improperly typed.

Please tell me how, I want to know how can I do it.